# Using vanilla JS to set image src from data-attribute

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I'm looking for a way to set the `src` of an image - in a modal - using the data attribute of a clickable element.

The markup for the element looks like this (there could be multiple of these on a page):

```html
<span class="tooltip" data-imageToSet="someimage.jpg">Click me</span>
<div id="modal">
  <img id="image" src="placeholder.jpg" />
</div>
<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal'),
    modalImage = document.getElementById('image');

  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('tooltip')) {
      modal.classList.toggle('shown');
      modalImage.src = event.currentTarget.dataset.imageToSet;
    }
  });
</script>
```

From what I've been reading up, this should work? But I keep getting a console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageToSet' of undefined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1)
```

Comment: `console.log(event.currentTarget)`

Comment: Tip: Why don't you bind the addEventListener directly on the tooltip element?

Comment: @KostasX when you have multiple elements.... Basics of event delegation

Comment: Oh, yes. I was looking at the code and forgot about the 'multiple' part in the description. Thanks @epascarello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. currentTarget will be the element you bound the click to so it will be document. The second issue is camel case does work with dataset, you need to use dash.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('modal'),
  modalImage = document.getElementById('image');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('tooltip')) {
    modal.classList.toggle('shown');
    console.log(event.target)
    modalImage.src = event.target.dataset.imageToSet;
  }
})
```

```html
<span class="tooltip" data-image-to-set="http://placekitten.com/300/300">Click me</span>


<div id="modal">
  <img id="image" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you check if the `target` (i.e. the element that is clicked) has the tooltip class

> ```
> event.target.classList.contains('tooltip')
> ```

But then you use the `currentTarget` (i.e. the element to which the event handler is bound: `document`) to read the dataset.

> ```
> modalImage.src = event.currentTarget.dataset.imageToSet
> ```

---

You need to continue to use the `target` throughout.